# margins not set properlly in VIEW in android

Tags: android, android-layout, layoutparams

Margins not set to the dynamically created view:-

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mDeleteBinLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(90, 90);

    mDeleteBinLayoutParams.setMargins(100, -20, 0, 10);

    final DeleteZone mDeleteZone = new DeleteZone(ThemeActivity.this);
    mDeleteZone.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete_zone);
    mDeleteZone.setId(-101);
    mDeleteZone.setLayoutParams(mDeleteBinLayoutParams);
    mDragLayer.addView(mDeleteZone);
```

Comment: why are you setting negative margin ?

Comment: I also checked with positive margins but its not working.

Comment: Is your  mDragLayer is a RelativeLayout

Comment: DragLayer is Absolute Layout using for Drag and Drop Functionality.

Comment: Then why are you setting RelativeLayoutParams

Answer (score 1):

The Solution for this i got:-

```
DragLayer.LayoutParams lp = new DragLayer.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    mProfile.getmCharsSize() + 50, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mDeleteBinLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(90, 90);
```

change this to

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mDeleteBinLayoutParams = mDeleteZone.getLayoutParams();
```